# What are good jQuery plugins to highlight code and XML content?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, syntax-highlighting

I have a couple of web-pages where I write out some code `c#`, and some `XML`. I'd like to find a way to highlight the syntax of the different content to make it easier to read - very much like here on Stackoverflow?

I already use a bit of jQuery so something that plugs into that would be a nice fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm, I don't see where jQuery fits in there too well (because it is for DOM modification, not based on the textual content of the DOM).

Still, you might want to take a look at the very cool [google-code-prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify). As far as I know, it is also used here at StackOverflow and it works like a charm for many languages. I use it myself and it's really easy to integrate.

Comment: funny looking back at the remarks here, since people seem to like to use jquery for anything and everything (http://www.mikedoesweb.com/2012/jquery-math-finally-solved/)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [Alex Gorbatchev's SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter). It's one of the nicest formatters out there, and supports tons of syntaxes if you ever decide to format code in a new language.

Answer (score 0):

- [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) supports 118 languages and 54 styles out of the box. It is BSD-licensed.
- Google's [Javascript code prettifier](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) also supports XML, License: Apache 2.0
- [Alex Gorbatchev's SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/)

Comment: If someone votes down, please explain in the comments